# JS str.split() won't work with data fetched with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split a string with JS.

I have two cases:
1234 & 1234-1

If i try to split the case with "-" it works fine.
But when the case is without the "-" it will give me an error:

> str1.indexOf is not a function
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.

I guess this has something todo with Jquery?

**JQUERY**

```
//THIS DON'T WORK
var nr = $(this).parent('td').siblings('.td_objNr').data('objnr'); // nr = 12345

var str1 = nr;
var str2 = "-";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    nr = nr.split('-');
    nr = nr[0];
}

//THIS WORKS
var nr = '12345';

var str1 = nr;
var str2 = "-";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    nr = nr.split('-');
    nr = nr[0];
}
```

Comment: The error implies that `nr` is an Element object, not a string. We can't solve that with the code you've shown, as the problem starts with the value you place in to `data`

Comment: It's pretty simple. `nr` is not what you think it is. Simply add a new line right below `var nr...` of `console.log(typeof nr)` and you'll see that it's not a string.

Comment: Or better yet, set a breakpoint on that line and look at the variable in the debugger. There's no reason to stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you can *turn on the lights* with the debugger built into your browser or IDE.

Comment: I don't disagree that the debugger is a nice way to check, but for something this simple. I can put a `console` test line in there and test it about 5x faster than doing it with the debugger. Also, since many people asking these simple types of questions on SO are new to the language or programming, it's a simpler set of instructions than explaining how to get into the debugger and set breakpoints and then where to look while paused for the information that we seek.

Comment: When the case is 12345, it's a number.. and when it's 1234-5 it's a string. So to solve this.. i have to convert the number to a string? Or is there a better way to remove the "-" if exist?

Comment: `12345` is most likely not a number because you are extracting it from an HTML element and all data in HTML is strings. (The "T" in HTML stands for Text). Again, add `console.log(typeof nr)` and you'll see that you first have an Object. You then need to extract the content from that object.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did console.log(typeof nr) right after the jquery fetch. And as i wrote.. it said number on 12345 and string on 1234-5.

Comment: You added my line after the **first** `var nr...` that you showed in your code? The one that doesn't work?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes

Comment: @ScottMarcus when you use jquery's `.data()` it will convert and return the correct type, so `<div data-val="123"/>` and `$("div").data("val") === 123` (note the ===) and `$("div").data("val") !== "123"`.  If you used `.attr("data-val")` then it will always be a string.

Comment: @freedomn-m And yet the OP is getting an error stating that he has an HTMLAnchorElement that he's trying to call `.indexOf` on.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's because i try to use str.split on a number.. when it's 12345.. and on a string when it's 1234-5.

Comment: Your showing us that you are getting this error: `str1.indexOf is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.` That is not the error you get with `12345`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that is indeed a strange error.  Back to Rory's comment at the top, it looks like the OP has done `$("el").data(otherElement)`.  But my comment was regarding your comment "12345 is not a number because it's from H*T*ML and all data is strings" which is not correct.

Comment: @freedomn-m I understand. That's not what I'm addressing. All of my comments are pertaining to what the OP stated the error was - - the HTMLAnchorElement.

Comment: For me. I'd like to get to the root of why that error is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jquery's `.data()` it will convert and return the correct type, so `<div data-val="123"/>` and `$("div").data("val") === 123` (note the ===) and `$("div").data("val") !== "123"`.

To ensure you get a string, you can:

- use `.attr("data-val")` then it will always be a string
- convert to a string using `val.toString`
- convert to a string using or `val+""`

```js
console.log('$("#t1").data("val") === 123', $("#t1").data("val") === 123)
console.log('$("#t1").data("val") === "123"', $("#t1").data("val") === "123")
console.log('$("#t2").data("val") === "123-1"', $("#t2").data("val") === "123-1")
console.log(' $("#t1").attr("data-val") === "123"', $("#t1").attr("data-val") === "123")
console.log('$("#t1").data("val")+"" === "123"', $("#t1").data("val")+"" === "123")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='t1' data-val="123">123</div>
<div id='t2' data-val="123-1">123-1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `str1` is number not string. You can convert it to string so you can use `.indexOf`.

```js
let str1 = 12345
console.log(str1.indexOf('-'))
```

```js
let str1 = "12345"
console.log(str1.indexOf('-'))
```

See [JQuery .data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for more details.
Here is the part where it explains why you get number instead of string.

> Every attempt is made to convert the attribute's string value to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A string is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change its representation (for example, the string "100" is converted to the number 100, but "1E02" and "100.000" are left as strings because their numeric value of 100 serializes to "100"). When a string starts with '{' or '[', then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse it; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. A string not parseable as a JavaScript value is not converted.
>
> To retrieve a data-* attribute value as an unconverted string, use the attr() method.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your variable is a number and not a string, what you could do is use `toString()`.

```
var nr = $(this).parent('td').siblings('.td_objNr').data('objnr'); // nr = 12345;

var str1 = nr.toString();
var str2 = "-";

if (str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    nr = nr.split('-');
    nr = nr[0];
}
```